# Function with multiple boolean conditions or multiple functions?

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to define a 'util' module for my project, where the base util function is 'display windows' (opencv project in this case):

```
def display_windows(windows_to_display, with_text=False):
    for window_tag, window in windows_to_display:
        cv2.imshow(window_tag, window)
```

In addition to the basic 'display', I want to have multiple options, say

1. Add text to the window (cv2.putText()
2. Wait after displaying windows (cv2.waitKey())
3. Destroy windows (cv2.destroyAllWindows())
   etc

I'm wondering how to approach this, one option is to add multiple boolean values with default values, and then have something like:

```
def display_windows(windows_to_display, with_text=False, with_wait=False, destroy_first=False):
    if destroy_first:
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    for window_tag, window in windows_to_display:
        if with_text:
            cv2.putText(window, 'text', ...)
        cv2.imshow(window_tag, window)
    if with_wait:
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Alternatively, I could declare several functions, use the 'base' 'display windows' and then add say:

```
def display_windows_and_wait(self, windows_to_display, with_text=False, destroy_first=False):
    display_windows(windows_to_display, with_text)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

etc.

I'm not completely happy with either choice; 
Going with the boolean approach, I'm not a big fan of having :

```
display_windows(windows, True, True, True)
```

scattered around, since it's not very informative.

Going with the multiple function approach, well, not sure if that helps really.

Any thoughts of which approach improved readability?
Or even better, is there a better way to approach this issue?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Instead of calling

   ```
   display_windows(windows, True, True, True)
   ```

   you may still use keys in arguments:

   ```
   display_windows(windows, with_text=True, with_wait=True, destroy_first=True)
   ```
2. You may first define some constants and then use them:

   ```
   WITH_TEXT = True         # possibly also NO_TEXT = False, NO_WAIT = False, etc.
   WITH_WAIT = True
   DESTROY_FIRST = True

   display_windows(windows, WITH_TEXT, WITH_WAIT, DESTROY_FIRST)
   ```
3. You may use only 1 parameter with bits as flags:

   ```
   WITH_TEXT = 0b001
   WITH_WAIT = 0b010
   DESTROY_FIRST = 0b100
   ```

   The example of calling your function:

   ```
   display_windows(windows, WITH_TEXT|DESTROY_FIRST)
   ```

   and the change in your function definition:

   ```
   def display_windows(windows_to_display, flags=0):
       if flags & DESTROY_FIRST:
           cv2.destroyAllWindows()
       # and so on
   ```

   The advantage of it — in calling your function:

   1. the flags (in the 2nd parameter) may be in *arbitrary order, *
   2. the flags with `False` value are simply *omitted.*

Comment: I like the first one, as it minimizes the risk of bugs. You can even swap arguments and it will still be right. The second one, by contrast, increases the risk of bugs substantially, as it even hides the potential problems of swapping the arguments in a way where it looks right but isn't. So I would definitely not recommend the second one. But the first one is great.

Comment: I added a 3rd alternative, IMHO the best one. —  If you like my answer, why don't accepting it and / or voting it up?

Comment: If I find part of an answer bad, I don't upvote it. In this case, I find the second suggestion bad practise. My comment was meant to be about how I find the second suggestion counter-productive and leading to bugs. If only the first one was mentioned, I would have upvoted the answer straight away. I also don't like the new third suggestion, as the valid values are not clear from the function definition (I know it's very common in C and C++, but I still don't like it), but that's somewhat minor. But suggestion 2 is straightout bad and bug-prone in my opinion.

Comment: I think I'll go with option 1, keeps it informative and clear. 
Thanks for offering multiple solutions, though have to say I'm not a fan of option 2 & 3.
:)

Comment: @DM15, you're welcome. Every option has its pro and cons.